# Redirection in php dynamic

Tags: php, redirect

I have problem in redirecting my url.

I have url:-

```
http://example.com/r/index.php?id=1234
```

it gives me value of url from database.I store the value of url in $url_link.

On the same page,after db operation.I add the redirect code in body part.

```
<?php    
header('Location: http://$url_link');    
?>
```

which doesnt take the value $url_link.

Comment: Going to need to see alot more code than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be something like this.

```
<?php    
  header('Location: http://'.$url_link);    
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Enclose in double quotes.. Variables inside single quotes will not get interpreted.

Do like this...

```
<?php    
header("Location: http://$url_link");    
?>
```